# Chrome: Basic Auth image requests return 401, but not when called directly

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, http-status-code-401

Chrome throws 401 restricted errors for Basic auth'd IMG-urls in the vein of http://user:pass@path.to/image, but did not do this before with the same resources and code. When called directly, as in "open in new tab" the images load without a hitch. I'm puzzled. Any ideas?

Comment: I've encountered the same. I guess it has something to do with the latest chrome update. In Firefox everything works as exspected.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue with Chrome v30.

Comment: After further research the issue has been raised with the Chromium team - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303046

Comment: If the image is hosted on a different domain from the webpage, and you try to do "Copy URL" it copies: "http://<webpage_domain/http://user:pass@path.to/image"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Chromium [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303046):

> cbentzel@chromium.org wrote:
>   This is an intentional change - there are lots of security/compatibility tradeoffs that we have to make when tightening up browser security and in this case the decision was made that the compatibility risk was worth it